# How to get button value using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, button, onclick

I am trying to figure out how to get the value of a button using JavaScript. There are several buttons generated using a while statement in php code, so the `name` and `id` are the same for all of them. The only difference between them is the value.

Part of my php code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td align=\"center\"><input type=\"button\" id=\"details\" name=\"details\" value=\"" . $row['mcn'] . "\" onClick=\"MCNdetails()\"></td>";
     echo "</tr>";
     }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that when this button is clicked a JavaScript alert is displayed with this records details.

(FYI - "Faker" is the form name that this table is a part of.)

My JavaScript code:

```
function MCNdetails()
        {

        var buttonDetails = document.Faker.details;
        var buttonValue = buttonDetails.value;

        if (buttonValue === "2700-2057" )
            {
            alert ("Details are here");
            return;
            }
        else
            {
            alert ("No Dice " + buttonValue);
            return;
            }

        }
```

I have approx. 300 records so far. When I click on ANY of the buttons I always get the else statement. I did try getting the element by id like this:

```
function MCNdetails()
        {

        var buttonDetails = document.getElementById("details");
        var buttonValue = buttonDetails.value;

        if (buttonValue === "2700-2057" )
            {
            alert ("Details are here");
            return;
            }
        else
            {
            alert ("No Dice " + buttonValue);
            return;
            }

        }
```

But that would always return the value of the first button regardless of which one I clicked.

I have done some Google searching as well as searching this site and I can't find this same scenario where the buttons are generated.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @NullPointer Is it bad form on Stackoverflow to have a signature at the bottom of the post? I also noticed that if I started the post with "hello" it also got deleted. Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: yes please dont use ... signature  and hello , greeting and like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getVal(value)
  {

   alert(value);
  }
 </script>
 <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="getVal(this.value)">
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I tried your code and it worked perfectly. I have used "this" in the past on one of my first projects, I wish I would have thought to use it as it clearly the right way to do it. I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: @AndrewFox yours very welcome.. all use at so would  love to help

Answer (score 5):

Note that using the same id for more than one element is invalid html, though most (all?) browsers tend not to make a fuss about it and they'll still display the page quite happily. That's why when you tried to use `document.getElementById("details")` it always gave you the first button with that id - how would the browser know which one you meant?

Having said that, if you pass `this` in the function call on click:

```
onClick=\"MCNdetails(this)\"
```

...that will give the function a direct reference to the particular button that was clicked. So then:

```
function MCNdetails(btn) {
    var buttonValue = btn.value;

    // etc
}
```

In which case your buttons don't really need ids at all. But if you do keep the ids you should find a way to make them unique (e.g., append a sequence number to the end of each).

Comment: When I tried the get element by id bit, I sort of knew what was going to happen, but couldn't help myself but to try it anyways :)
I tried your code but it didn't work, is "btn" suppose to be replaced with the name of the button? I tried both but neither worked. I have no doubt it didn't work only because of something on my end.
Regardless, I appreciate the info, I definitely learned something new and that's always good.

Comment: Also wanted to mention that I removed the id's as you suggested, I like to have proper code.

Comment: It should work as I've shown. No, `btn` is not supposed to be replaced with the name of the button - it's the name of the function argument as used within the function like I showed. This is exactly the same principle as in NullPointer's answer, except where that answer passed `this.value` as an argument my answer passed `this` and then got the value within the function from `btn.value`. If one works the other should too. Anyway, probably no point messing around with it any further if you've used the other answer successfully.

Comment: I know curiosity killed the cat, but I couldn't help myself, I had to try it. 
You are right, it works...I don't know what I did wrong the first time, but it definitely works. Thanks again :)