# How to check button value in java script

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I wanna check button value in java script(mvc),here is mycode:

```
            <span>
            <input type="button" value='@L("Follow")'  onclick='return   follow(this)' />
        </span>
```

and in my js:

```
function follow(btn) {
if ($(btn).defaultvalue == "Follow") {
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132252/how-to-get-button-value-using-javascript

Comment: JS is case sensitive. It'd be `defaultValue`.

Comment: @MarcB: it works!TNX

Answer (score 0):

Jquery

```
function follow() {
  var buttonVal = $('button').val();
 // do your check 
}
```